# Perl Syslog Parser

Tags: regex, perl

I am currently trying to create a script that will test a regular expression containing keyword against the syslog file. However in attempting to match the expression against positive finds, I am unable to retrieve results. For the record I have checked the file to ensure there are records associated with that I wish to find. I was hoping if anybody has an idea of where the expression is incorrect.

I am using an if statement to test the expression against an entry as below:

Against an entry such as

```
Jan  5 00:37:50 Steves-MBP.default sessionlogoutd[1309]: sessionlogoutd Launched
```

Any help at all is much appreciated. Cheers guys

As requested, an entry that should correctly match would be something such as, with networkmanager as word:

```
Dec  3 06:13:24 kali NetworkManager[2572]: <info>  address 172.5.2.145
```

Comment: Note that your regex will fail for dates like `Jan 10`, since only one space is used for padding.

Comment: to follow on @ThisSuitIsBlackNot comment: replace `\s\s` with `\s\s*` (or: `\s+`) to allow for "one or more" separators instead of "exactly 2"

Comment: The example line you have given won't match against the word "kernel event". Give the relevant word(s) for this line or a line with "kernel event" in it.

Comment: Can I suggest that if you're syslog parsing, you might want to consider `logstash`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you chomp your input you should replace `\n` with `$`.

```
$word = "networkmanager";
$log = "Dec  3 06:13:24 kali NetworkManager[2572]: <info>  address 172.5.2.145";
# Note the "i".
if ($log =~ m/([A-Z]\w*\s\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s.*\s$word.*$)/i) {
    print "yes\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Done that, but still no results.

Comment: Post more of your code. I've added the code that matches the log line you've given on my machine.

Comment: @Alyn Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27782716/edit) your question and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in a reproducible manner. That will make it easier for other users to find the issue and help you fix it. Note that we should be able to copy the code from your question verbatim and run it in our own environment.

Comment: @Alyn Also post a word you want to match your example line against.

Comment: Seems to be working now. It will also find other words which are needed. I very much appreciate the time you, and everyone else, has taken to help me out on a problem I doubt I would have solved myself. Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install or use cpan modules, there appears to be one that does what you need:
http://search.cpan.org/~dschwei/Parse-Syslog/